# Detecting dropped call in Mobile

Tags: mobile, mobile-phones, java-me

I'm using Motorola device and developed it with J2ME . I'm searching for a functionality to detect incomming or outcomming calls when dropped .
I mean , when the call is dropped I need to recognize this event.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

There is no standard J2ME telephony API.

There could be a working proprietary java-based API on that particular handset but that's both unlikely and not obvious to verify.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the life-cycle of the application to detect interrupts. Your device can detect when a phone-call comes in and ends, and trigger shownotify(), hidenotify(), startApp(), pauseApp(), then do something accordingly. See the [canvas class](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Canvas.html). So if you have an application running, you can detect an incoming phone-call, wait for it to end then do something. This is of course very device/manufacturer specific and you are in a world of hurt when it comes to porting this for many devices. I'm not sure if you can do something like this for outgoing calls, since your app will be in the background and paused for most devices.

Answer (score -1):

You could try checking the motorola developer webpage. Motorola has its own set of libraries for j2me, it may support the case you need.